# Host Angular 4 on Apache2 (Ubuntu 14.04 Server)

Tags: angular, apache2, host

I can't find a decent explanation as to how to do this. Every single one I found used a completely different approach, which all either refered to folders/files that didn't exist on my system to edit or just straight up didn' function.

I deployed my project using `ng build`. Then I put it in the `/var/www/` folder. When I access the index.html, nothing happens. None of the javascript is executed. I created a .conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` linking to my folder. Nothing happens. (I used `service apache2 restart` after every approach). What do I need to do? How do I host the app like I do with `ng serve`?

Comment: There is information on the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers

Comment: I edited my .htaccess file and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

The base tag in your index.html file contains the name of the base directory containing your app folder, which in your case sounds like `/var/www`

You then need to use the appropriate flag on the `ng build` to set the flag.

From the documentation:

> When building you can modify base tag () in your
>   index.html with --base-href your-url option.
>
> ## Sets base tag href to /myUrl/ in your index.html ng build --base-href /myUrl/ ng build --bh /myUrl/

Comment: Okay, I have no idea how this can happen but for some reason (I literally didn't edit any files) I get a "You don't have permission to access /dist/ on this server." when I try to access now. Worked fine a couple minutes ago.